# Celery execution time

Tags: celery, django-celery

I already have an email_sender function using Celery; each email takes 3 seconds to send, and i want to improve my function.
so i need Celery to do something like this:
`send email_num[1:500] ---> each email send in 20 second send email_num[500:1500] ---> each email send in 15 second send email_num[1500:5000] ---> each email send in 10 second send email_num[5000:] ---> each email send in 5 second`
is there any solution?

I tried to set dynamic time for a task.